# When I call logout it changes the jsessionid, but still allows me to access other paths without having to log in

Tags: spring, security, logout

I'm attempting to logout using Spring Security, but any time I call the logout url it changes the jsessionid, but I can still access urls that should be restricted and ask for me to log back in.

```
public void configure(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception{

        httpSecurity.httpBasic();

        httpSecurity.authorizeRequests()
                .mvcMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/privateEvent").hasAuthority("REGISTERED_USER")
                .mvcMatchers(HttpMethod.DELETE, "/privateEvent/*").hasAuthority("RSVP_ADMIN")
                .mvcMatchers("/registerPrivateEvent").hasAuthority("REGISTERED_USER")
                .mvcMatchers("/guestList").hasAuthority("EVENT_PUBLISHER")
                .mvcMatchers("/eventPublishersList").hasAuthority("RSVP_ADMIN")
                .anyRequest().permitAll()
         .and()
                .logout()
                .invalidateHttpSession(true)
                .deleteCookies("JSESSIONID")
                .deleteCookies("XSRF-TOKEN")
                .clearAuthentication(true)
                .logoutRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/logout"))
                .logoutSuccessUrl("/allDone")
                .permitAll()
          .and()
                .csrf().disable();
}
```

Comment: Looks like you are missing .authenticated(). Try this - .anyRequest().authenticated().

Comment: I added .anyRequest().authenticated() before the first .and() and it still gives me the same issue.

Comment: Post your logout controller method too.

Comment: Basic authentication and logout don't work. When logged in once, each request will include the basic authentication header. Basically you are logging in after you have logged out. If you are using a javascript solution in the browser, clear the header there as well, if you are relying on the browser, you basically cannot logout then.